# AES using Base64 Encryption

Tags: java, base64, aes

my target is to encrypt a String with AES
I am using Base64 for encryption, because AES needs a byte array as input.
Moreover i want every possible Char(including chinese and german Symbols) to be stored correctly

```
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64 ("some input");
System.out.println(new Base64().encodeToString(encryptedBytes));
```

I thought "some input" should be printed. Instead "someinpu" is printed.
It is impossible for me to use sun.misc.* Instead i am using apache.commons.codec

Does someone has a clue what's going wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes - "some input" isn't a valid base64 encoded string.

The idea of base64 is that you encode *binary* data into *text*. You then decode that *text* data to a byte array. You can't just decode any arbitrary text as if it were a complete base64 message any more than you can try to decode an mp3 as a jpeg image.

Encrypting a string should be this process:

- Encode the string to binary data, e.g. using UTF-8 (`text.getBytes("UTF-8")`)
- Encrypt the binary data using AES
- Encode the cyphertext using Base64 to get text

Decryption is then a matter of:

- Decode the base64 text to the binary cyphertext
- Decrypt the cyphertext to get the binary plaintext
- Decode the binary plaintext into a string using the same encoding as the first step above, e.g. `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Base64 to turn arbitrary text into bytes; that's not what it's designed to do.

Instead, you should use UTF8:

```
byte[] plainTextBytes = inputString.getBytes("UTF8");

String output = new String(plainTextBytes, "UTF8");
```